# How to use several date classes for code generation by openapi-generator-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I am using openapi-generator-maven-plugin with next config:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>spring-code-generation</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <typeMappings>
                            <typeMapping>OffsetDateTime=ZonedDateTime</typeMapping>
                        </typeMappings>
                        <importMappings>
                            <importMapping>java.time.OffsetDateTime=java.time.ZonedDateTime</importMapping>
                        </importMappings>
                        <inputSpec>
                            ${project.basedir}/openapi.yml
                        </inputSpec>
                        <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                        <apiPackage>api-swagger.api</apiPackage>
                        <modelPackage>api-swagger.model</modelPackage>
                        <supportingFilesToGenerate>
                            ApiUtil.java
                        </supportingFilesToGenerate>
                        <configOptions>
                            <sourceFolder>src/main/java/</sourceFolder>
                            <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                            <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                            <library>spring-boot</library>
                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I need to have ability to use several datetime java classes for my models - some needs to be ZonedDateTime, some other LocalDateTime and another needs to be Date class.

Something like this:

```
 SomeDto:
  required:
    - dateTime
  type: object
  properties:
    dateTime:
      type: string
      format: ZonedDateTime

 SomeOtherDto:
  required:
    - dateTime
  type: object
  properties:
    dateTime:
      type: string
      format: LocalDateTime
```

Can I have such a logic by using openapi-generator-maven-plugin ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are so close.  Try this:

```xml
<typeMappings>
    <typeMapping>OffsetDateTime=OffsetDateTime</typeMapping>
    <typeMapping>ZonedDateTime=ZonedDateTime</typeMapping>
    <typeMapping>LocalDateTime=LocalDateTime</typeMapping>
</typeMappings>
<importMappings>
    <importMapping>OffsetDateTime=java.time.OffsetDateTime</importMapping>
    <importMapping>ZonedDateTime=java.time.ZonedDateTime</importMapping>
    <importMapping>LocalDateTime=java.time.LocalDateTime</importMapping>
</importMappings>
```

What this is doing is telling the generator that any type of OffsetDateTime is equal to the class `OffsetDateTime`.  Then, it tells the generator that any time the class `OffsetDateTime` is used, the import for that class is `java.time.OffsetDateTime`.

So, you can also have custom type mappings that will still use the java class.  You don't have to name them after the class name.  For example, the following will still work:

```xml
<typeMappings>
    <typeMapping>offset=OffsetDateTime</typeMapping>
    <typeMapping>zoned=ZonedDateTime</typeMapping>
    <typeMapping>local=LocalDateTime</typeMapping>
</typeMappings>
<importMappings>
    <importMapping>OffsetDateTime=java.time.OffsetDateTime</importMapping>
    <importMapping>ZonedDateTime=java.time.ZonedDateTime</importMapping>
    <importMapping>LocalDateTime=java.time.LocalDateTime</importMapping>
</importMappings>
```

when used with this schema:

```yaml
    SomeDto:
      required:
        - dateTime
      type: object
      properties:
        dateTime:
          type: string
          format: zoned
    SomeOtherDto:
      required:
        - dateTime
      type: object
      properties:
        dateTime:
          type: string
          format: local
    EvenAnotherDto:
      required:
        - dateTime
      type: object
      properties:
        dateTime:
          type: string
          format: offset
```

Furthermore, you can declare the imports inline if you would like, and not worry about the `importMappings` at all.

```xml
<typeMappings>
    <typeMapping>OffsetDateTime=java.time.OffsetDateTime</typeMapping>
    <typeMapping>ZonedDateTime=java.time.ZonedDateTime</typeMapping>
    <typeMapping>LocalDateTime=java.time.LocalDateTime</typeMapping>
</typeMappings>
```

It's really up to you.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but with your second config example all dates are generated as Strings.

Comment: Problem was about using : and " signs in your example. I've edited your comment. Now it works! Thanks!

Comment: oh, yes, sorry about that.  I use gradle, so wasn't sure of the syntax.  Thanks.